# symmetric difference for arrays with objects JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
let arr1 = [{ countryCode: "ITA", index: 2, name: "Italy"}, { countryCode: "NLD", index: 1, name: "Netherlands"}];

let arr2 = [{ countryCode: "NLD", index: 1, name: "Netherlands"}, { countryCode: "BEL", index: 3, name: "Belgium"}];
```

I want it to return the symmetric difference, so it should return:

```
[{ countryCode: "ITA", index: 2, name: "Italy"},  {countryCode: "BEL", index: 3, name: "Belgium"}]
```

How can I accomplish this in Javascript? I tried to do the following:

```
let difference = arr1
                 .filter(x => !arr2.includes(x))
                 .concat(arr2.filter(x => !arr1.includes(x)));
```

But this doesn't seem to work for arrays with objects in them.

Comment: The reason is because equality checks on objects checks only the reference to the object, not each and every one of its key:value pairs.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a `Map` and add or delete the item, if it is in the map.

```js
const
    array1 = [{ countryCode: "ITA", index: 2, name: "Italy"}, { countryCode: "NLD", index: 1, name: "Netherlands" }],
    array2 = [{ countryCode: "NLD", index: 1, name: "Netherlands" }, { countryCode: "BEL", index: 3, name: "Belgium" }],
    map = new Map,
    cb = o => map.delete(o.countryCode) || map.set(o.countryCode, o);

array1.forEach(cb);
array2.forEach(cb);

console.log(Array.from(map.values()));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd collect one of the unique values in the objects (like `countryCode`) into an array of just those values, then you can use your original approach:

```js
const arr1 = [{ countryCode: "ITA", index: 2, name: "Italy"}, { countryCode: "NLD", index: 1, name: "Netherlands"}];
const arr2 = [{ countryCode: "NLD", index: 1, name: "Netherlands"}, { countryCode: "BEL", index: 3, name: "Belgium"}];

const arr1Codes = arr1.map(a => a.countryCode);
const arr2Codes = arr2.map(a => a.countryCode);

const result = arr1
  .filter(a => !arr2Codes.includes(a.countryCode))
  .concat(arr2.filter(a => !arr1Codes.includes(a.countryCode)));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first get the `set` of the unique country codes and then get the unique elements in each array using `.filter`:

```js
const arr1 = [
  { countryCode: "ITA", index: 2, name: "Italy"}, 
  { countryCode: "NLD", index: 1, name: "Netherlands"}
];
const arr2 = [
  { countryCode: "NLD", index: 1, name: "Netherlands"}, 
  { countryCode: "BEL", index: 3, name: "Belgium"}
];

const arr = [...arr1, ...arr2];
const countryCodes = arr.map(e => e.countryCode);

const uniqueCountryCodes = new Set(
  countryCodes.filter(e => countryCodes.indexOf(e) === countryCodes.lastIndexOf(e))
);

const difference = arr.filter(x => uniqueCountryCodes.has(x.countryCode));

console.log(difference);
```